# How to draw a contrast outline around vector objects in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, education

Some designers draw a border line around their artwork (for example: a logo). Most likely for the purpose of maintaining image contrast if the user displays the image in dark mode browser. I'm referring to the white line around the artwork in the image below.

Questions:

1- What is the correct term of this specific technique/effect?

2- Is there a simple way of achieving it for Vector art in Inkscape?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no special term, although you could just call it an ***outline***, and there are several techniques that could be used.

A semi-automated method is to make a copy of the design, make sure everything is ungrouped until there are no groups left, and do *Path > Union* or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Then do *Path > Dynamic Offset* or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, and adjust the control to enlarge the shape

Then place it behind the artwork by sending it to the bottom of the stack.

Example

[image]

Another method instead of adding a dynamic offset would be to apply a thick stroke to the United shape instead.

A more manual option is to draw around the shape with the Bézier tool, apply a fill, and again, place it behind the artwork.  I like this method the best, as it's the simplest, and allows for total control of the outline.

Example

[image]

Comment: I have updated the title of the question to use the term "outline", so that this outstanding answer is more reachable by others.

Comment: Just made a feature request for the offset LPE: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/1604